# onSharedPreferenceChanged for MultiSelectListPreference not always work

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have the following problem:
`onSharedPreferenceChanged` is called only the first time I change value in `MultiSelectListPreference`, but never again. When I restart PrefernceActiviy all preferences all kept, and one again `onSharedPreferenceChanged` is called only the first time.

The things I've done:

1. I treat my `PreferenceActivity` as a 'OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener' (I don't create annonymous class)
2. I register and unregister `this` object in `onResume()` and `onPause`
3. I try to get `SharedPreference` in two way, as 

   a) getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()

   a) new SharedPreferences(this)

   but both ways worked exactly the same

What am I doing wrong?

---

Posted code:

```
object PreferencesActivity {
    final val KEY_AUTO_REFRESH = "preference_auto_refresh"
    final val KEY_REFRESH_PERIOD = "preference_refresh_period"
    final val KEY_NOTIFICATIONS = "preference_notifications"
    final val KEY_AUTO_MARK_AS_READ = "preference_auto_mark_as_read"
    final val KEY_CHECKED_RADIO_BUTTON = "preference_checked_radio"
    final val KEY_SHOW_SELECTED_ONLY = "preference_show_selected_only"
    final val KEY_KEEP_READ_FEEDS = "preference_keep_read_feeds"

    private final val DEFAULT_REFRESH_PERIOD = "10"
}

class PreferencesActivity extends SherlockPreferenceActivity with OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    private lazy val sharedPreferences = getPreferenceScreen.getSharedPreferences

    override def onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) = {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences)
        getSupportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }

    override def onResume = {
        super.onResume
        getPreferenceScreen.getSharedPreferences
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)

        configureRefreshPeriod
        configureNotificationsType
    }

    override def onPause = {
        super.onPause
        getPreferenceScreen.getSharedPreferences
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this)
    }

    private def configureRefreshPeriod = {
        val textViewRefreshPeriod = findPreference(KEY_REFRESH_PERIOD)
        textViewRefreshPeriod.setSummary(getNotificationPeriod)
    }

    private def getNotificationPeriod = {
        val refreshPeriodValue = sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_REFRESH_PERIOD, DEFAULT_REFRESH_PERIOD)
        val summaryRefreshPeriod_general = getString(R.string.preference_period_summary)
        val summaryRefreshPeriod_concrete = String.format(summaryRefreshPeriod_general, refreshPeriodValue.toString)
        summaryRefreshPeriod_concrete
    }

    private def configureNotificationsType = {
        val textViewNotifications = findPreference(KEY_NOTIFICATIONS)
        textViewNotifications.setSummary(getNotificationKinds)
    }

    private def getNotificationKinds = {
        val notificationsSet = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(KEY_NOTIFICATIONS, new HashSet)

        if (!notificationsSet.isEmpty)
            getString(R.string.preference_notifications_summary_checked) +
                getStringValuesFromSet(notificationsSet)
        else
            getString(R.string.preference_notifications_summary_unchecked)

    }

    private def getStringValuesFromSet(notificationsSet: Set[String]) = {
        notificationsSet.toArray.mkString(", ")
    }

    override def onSharedPreferenceChanged(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences, key: String) =
        key match {
            case `KEY_REFRESH_PERIOD` => configureRefreshPeriod
            case `KEY_NOTIFICATIONS` => configureNotificationsType
            case _ =>
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was having a similar problem and I found a solution. I don't know if it can help you but I'm going to explain it anyway, hoping it will be useful.

I initially put the Listener in the PreferenceActivity but it wasn't working as I wished, so I moved the PreferenceChangeListener to my MainActivity (because in my App preferences can be changed in different places from the PreferenceActivity).

I created this class in MainActivity.java:

```
private class PreferenceChangeListener implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {

        // Function to manage changes
        somethingChanged();
    }
}
```

And I am instantiating it in MainActivity onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // mPreferenceListener is a private attribute of MainActivity.java
    mPreferenceListener = new PreferenceChangeListener();  
    settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(mPreferenceListener);

    [..]

}
```

In this way the Listener is intercepting correctly any Preferences changes, including MultiSelectListPreference.

Comment: Actually I can't do it like that, because my `PreferenceChangeListener` is used only to change summary in `PreferenceActivity` so it can't be kept anywhere else.

Comment: I deliberately didn't posted it cause it's in Scala, but as u wish.

Comment: I don't know Scala, but the code is clear anyway. I could suggest you to remove the unregistration in "onPause", as I don't understand why to put it there, when you wrote that the preferences are changed only in PreferenceActivity? So there's no explicit need to remove the registration.

Comment: Preferences are changed in a couple of places in my application, but I need listener only in `PreferenceActivity` for its preferences because I want to change preference summary depending on preference value so I have to unregister it there because I don't want to listen changes when something other change my preferences.

Comment: Did you try to use a flag instead of registering/unregistering the listener? In other words, set a flag "activeListener" to true in onResume and to false onPause.
You could then checking the flag value inside the listener procedure.

It's not very elegant but it could help you to find the source of your problem.

Comment: Even when I don't unregister listener, problem remains.